# Merge a Flowable<A> with a Single<B>

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I have two different documents with a relation:

```
class Foo {
    String getBarId();
    String message();
}
class Bar {
    String id();
    String description();
}
```

Given an `Flowable` of `Foo` I have to merge every item emitted with a `Single` of `Bar`. Imagine in non Reactive way the following:

```
getStreamOfFoo().forEach(f -> {
           Bar b = getBarById(f.getBarId());
           sendMessage(f.getMessage(), bar.getDescription());
});
```

So I have the method `getStreamOfFoo` that returns a `Flowable<Foo>`, the `getBarById` the returns a `Single<Bar>` and the `sendMessage` that returns a `Completable`.
This is my code, there is a compiling error that I don't know how to manage:

```
getFoo().flatMapCompletable(f ->
        Single.zip(Single.just(f), getBarById(f.getBarId()),
        (foo,bar) -> sendMessage(foo,bar)));
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, resolved, I was near to the solution. This is the code:

```
Completable sendMessage() {
     getFoo().map(f -> 
         Single.zip(
            Single.just(f),
            getBarById(f.getBarId()),
            (foo,bar) -> sendMessage(foo, bar)))
     .flatMapCompletable(identity());
}
```